# splitting a long table

Tags: longtable

I have the following long table and I want to split it into two pages.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{soul}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{authblk}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}


\FloatBarrier
\begin{table}[!htbp]
{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a bit of visual "breathing space"
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C|C|C|C|C|C|}
\hline
\textbf{a} & \textbf{b} & \textbf{c} & \textbf{d} & \textbf{e} & \textbf{f} \\ \hline
000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 \\ \hline
000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 \\ \hline
000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 \\ \hline
000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 \\ \hline
000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 \\ \hline
000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 \\ \hline
000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 \\ \hline
000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 \\ \hline
000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 \\ \hline
000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Remove `table` float environment.It prevent split `longtable` between pages. However, so far you use simple `tabularx` which not enable to  split table. See if packages `ltablex` or `xltabular` is what you looking for.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the `xltabular` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X} 

\usepackage{lipsum} % Only for dummy text. Remove in real document.

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]\lipsum[1]

{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|C|C|C|C|C|C|}
\hline
\textbf{a} & \textbf{b} & \textbf{c} & \textbf{d} & \textbf{e} & \textbf{f} \\ \hline
\endhead
000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 \\ \hline
000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 \\ \hline
000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 \\ \hline
000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 \\ \hline
000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 \\ \hline
000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 \\ \hline
000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 \\ \hline
000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 \\ \hline
000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 \\ \hline
000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 & 000 \\ \hline
\end{xltabular}}

\end{document}
```